# Classes and Dependencies imports issues in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, gson, drools

I'm facing some errors in my Maven project. My project structure is shown in the following image.
[image: "project structure"]

I define the class ProjectInfosDAO in the package `main.resources.utils` and the others are in `main.java.io.r2devops.jobSelector`.
`ProjectInfos` class is called in `JobSelector` class.
When I compile the project the following error is displayed:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol: variable ProjectDAO
  location: class io.r2devops.jobSelector.JobSelector
```

Also the similar error occurs for the dependency Gson despite I mentionned it in `pom.xml` and imported it in `ProjectInfosDAO`.

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol: variable Gson
  location: class main.resources.utils.ProjectInfosDAO
```

In `JobSelector` class:

```
 import main.resources.ProjectInfosDAO;
 
 public class JobSelector{
    public static final void main(String[] args){
       ...
       HashMap<String, TechnoInfos> technoInfos = ProjectInfosDAO.getTechnologiesInfos("technologies_infos.json"); 
       ...
    }
 }
```

In the `pom.xml`:

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>${drools-version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!--  Gson: Java to JSON conversion -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
...
```

Thanks in advance for your kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the problem mentioned by Roddy, the problem you have is with Maven. In Maven, `<dependencyManagement>` is not used to define the dependencies of your project, but to define the versions and scope of them. This is normally useful in a multi-module project.
So, even if you have a `<dependencyManagement>` in your `pom.xml`, you still need to define the dependencies:

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>${drools-version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!--  Gson: Java to JSON conversion -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
...
```

Or, if you are not in a multi-module project, you can probably get rid of the whole `<dependencyManagement>` section:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I realized the mistake and correct it and it's okay now.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put java classes in `src/main/resources`. Java classes go in `src/main/java`.

Comment: Thanks @Roddy. I moved `ProjectInfosDAO` in src/main/java but I still get the error about `import com.google.gson.Gson; import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;` which cannot be resolved, resulting to symbol: class Gson and class TypeToken not found.